# NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController and hidden property

Tags: cocoa, nsview, appkit, nsviewcontroller, nstitlebaraccessoryviewcontroller

Recently '*discovered*' `NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController` and love it -
except I need my apps to work under 10.11 and the `hidden` property doesn't exist until 10.12.

Any suggestions how to **smoothly** show/hide an `NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController` instance before 10.12, i.e. animate the view out/in?

I've tried adding a height constraint and animating it (i.e. the constraints `constant` property - but `NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController` automatically gets an auto resize constraint (even when turning it off before inserting the view) that causes Auto Layout exceptions as it forces the view to its initial height and prevents changing it..

Changing the view's `frame` property via the `animator` proxy also doesn't result in an animated change of the view's height.

Comment: Have you tried to just remove it with removeFromParentViewController?

Comment: Oh, sorry - it's not about adding/removing the view.. it's about doing so *smoothly*, i.e. animating the view in/out. That's easily done with the `hidden` property on 10.12+ but not obvious on 10.11

Comment: I would just ignore the animation part on 10.11, because back porting is such a time sucker. Any how, how about the viewController.view.hidden property?

Comment: Doesn't seem to have any impact on 10.11.. just hides/shows the view, no animation :-/

Comment: Try viewController.view.alphaValue.